# How to restore single specific column from MySQL dump via shell command?

Tags: mysql, ssh

How to restore only one certain column from a MySQL dump via ssh command?

To restore whole database it goes like this:

```
mysql -u [user] -p[pass] db < db_dump.sql
```

But I need to restore only a specific column in one of the tables.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dump file contains INSERT statements that restore whole rows, not individual columns. So you can't restore just one column.

What you can do is restore it to a second database

```
mysqladmin -u [user] -p[pass] create db2 
mysql -u [user] -p[pass] db2 < db_dump.sql
```

Then you can get into the SQL environment and copy the one column to the main database on respective rows.

```
mysql> UPDATE db.mytable JOIN db2.mytable USING (id)
       SET db.one_column = db2.one_column;
```

I'm of course making assumptions about the name of your table and column to copy, and the primary key column. But it should serve as a generic example to get you started.

Comment: That will do, perfect! Thank you. :)